# eclipse problems on casper notebook

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am using a Casper cky 3632-bt45v-f notebook and I am learning Android. I downloaded the SDK and ADT bundle. I started studying on Android two months ago. Now I have problems with Eclipse. If I create a new project, Eclipse does not create Java files in src folder and xml files in res/layout. I download the Android bundles again from https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=sk
But problem is not solved. What can I do?